# Magento 2.2.2 - Import Product Images Categorically

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, importexport

To import all the product images, we are using below approach

1. On the Magento server, upload the image files to the default folder
   for importing product images: `pub/media/import`
2. In the CSV data, enter the name of each image file to be imported on
   the correct row, by SKU, and in the correct column according to
   image type (base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image, or
   additional_images).

[image]

Here I can upload all the prod images under folder `pub/media/import`. I have 10 categories and products associated with those categories.

- How do I upload product images categorically? For example create
  folders with category name in `pub/media/import` like
  `pub/media/import/categoryA`, `pub/media/import/categoryB` and in `CSV` image path is
  `categoryA/prod-image-a.png`, `categoryB/prod-image-b.png`

Answer (score 0):

You should import two times by separate file. While importing first time, you can set images directory to `pub/media/import/categoryA` and while importing second time, you can set images directory to `pub/media/import/categoryB`. In `CSV` file, write only image name.

Comment: The store has around 50 categories. It will  be tedious to import one by one.